# How to implement Chebyshev Type 2 LPF in Java?

Tags: java, filter, signals, signal-processing, lowpass-filter

My raw signal graph is as follows.

What I intend to do is to do the "real peak" detection. That is the sawtooth-like noise peaks in the raw signal should not be counted.
[image]

After the Chebyshev Type 2 LPF implemented in Python, the signal is smoothed into the following graph.
[image]

As can be seen, I  can implement the LPF in Python.

But my problem is to implement it in Java.

**Is there any readily-built LPF that suits my purpose?
Or anyone can teach me how to do this in Java?**

The parameters are as follows:

Cut-off freq. = 4Hz.
Sampling rate = 350Hz.

Comment: I'm not aware of any code available to do this in java (which is not to say it doesn't exist) but you already have the filter designed in python, so why not just use the coefficients from your exiting design?

Comment: @BjornRoche  yea, true, I can recycle the parameters. but determining the parameters is the easiest part... The difficulty lies in the other parts.

Comment: How so? What order is the filter? (You didn't specify that in your question)

Comment: If you give your parameters, I can show you how to implement the filter in Java (or C, or whatever).

Comment: @BjornRoche  As for the order, I do not have a very strict number, as  I will adjust to achieve the optimal result later. You can take it as 10. THanks! I need the codes in JAVA. :)

Comment: @BjornRoche  then maybe a 3 0rder one?

Comment: That's more likely what you want. The answer below will work for 3rd order as well, you just need to change the 10s to 3s and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to implement a filter like this. [Direct Form I](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/filters/Direct_Form_I.html) is both straightforward and numerically stable, so I'll recommend that. I'll show double precision numbers for recursive variables to ensure accuracy. You may want to use doubles all around to avoid conversions, but I'll show with float and double so you can see where you really need the doubles.

I don't have code handy for a high order filter like this, so this is untested, but the concepts here and the link above will get you the answer. You can always compare your results to the python results.

First, you should already have coefficients of the following form:

```
float a[10] = { ... }
float b[10] = { ... }
```

Now, you'll want to make sure the coefficients are normalized, if they aren't already:

```
for( int i=0; i<10; ++i )
    b[i] /= a[0];
for( int i=1; i<10; ++i )
    a[i] /= a[0];
```

You're last setup step will be to create your memory buffers to store old inputs (x) and outputs (y):

```
float x[10] = { 0, 0, 0, ... }
double y[10] = { 0, 0, 0, ... }
```

When "reseting" the filter for a new dataset, remember to set the values of those to 0 again.

Now you are ready to start processing. This involves two steps: 1. calculating your output, and 2. updating your stored values.

```
float processOneValue( float in ) {
    // calculate new output:
    double out = in * b[0] ;
    for( int i=0; i<9; ++i )
       out += x[i]*b[i+1] ;
    for( int i=0; i<9; ++i )
       out -= y[i]*a[i+1] ;

    // update:
    for( int i=9; i>=1; --i )
       y[i] = y[i-1];
    y[0] = out;

    for( int i=9; i>=1; --i )
       x[i] = x[i-1];
    x[0] = in;

    return out;
}
```

Since this is such a high order filter, it might be more efficient to use a ringbuffer rather than the "bucket-brigade" style updates I used for x and y, but this works and is simpler to read.

Now, to process an array of data, just loop on processOneValue(). You can obtain the output in place or in a new array.

Comment: A little more info on DF I and some working code for a low order filter (2nd order) is here: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2012/08/basic-audio-eqs.html the code is in C but its very close to java.